# Verify if user is logged in in nextjs when using express as backend

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I have the following endpoint created in another project, I am using expressjs as a back end in there.

```
http://localhost:3001/auth/login # to login { username: string, password: string }
http://localhost:3001/auth/whoami # to check if you're logged in or not. responds with 401 or 200 status code and the body of { status: 'success' | 'failed' }
```

So. In order to login, in my login page in my next app, I send an axios request to my expressjs back-end. it responds in return with a cookie that holds a jwt token.

```js
const handleFormSubmit = () => client.post('/auth/login', { username, password })
```

Also, the `client` variable in the snippet above is an axios instance:

```js
export const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAIN_API,
  withCredentials: true,
})
```

Alright, it works and everything is cool.

Now I only have to protect my pages, so I have to somehow check if the user is logged in or not.

In order to do that I decided to use **middleware.ts** for that.

So. I have created a **middleware.ts** file:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import client from './services/mainApi/client'

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const mainAPI = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAIN_API
  const loginPageUrl = new URL('/auth/login', req.nextUrl.origin)

  const { data } = await client.get('/auth/whoami')
  if (data.status !== 'success') return NextResponse.redirect(loginPageUrl.toString())
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     * - auth/*
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|auth).*)',
    '/',
  ],
}
```

That's what I have tried.

1. I feel like what I am doing is not standard and people do better.
2. I think this code will send an HTTP request for every request to the backend to verify if the user is logged in or not (there's no caching (?) because in middleware everything runs before the cache).
3. Using axios gives an error. because according to my understanding, **middleware** only works on the edge. So in order to make it work, we can't use axios, because axios relies on something that Edge does not support (idk). it gives this error:

```
Server Error
AxiosError: There is no suitable adapter to dispatch the request since :
- adapter xhr is not supported by the environment
- adapter http is not available in the build

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
src/middleware.ts (8:32) @ get

   6 | const loginPageUrl = new URL('/auth/login', req.nextUrl.origin)
   7 |
>  8 | const { data } = await client.get('/auth/whoami')
     |                              ^
   9 | if (data.status !== 'success') return NextResponse.redirect(loginPageUrl.toString())
  10 | }
  11 |
```

[image]

Now, how can I check if my users are logged in or not?

I don't use Nextjs as a backend, I use express to talk to my database and do all the stuff, nextjs is just for the front end.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using fetch instead of axios?

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic, yes but the problem was I needed the with Credentials I used to have in axios. See the accepted answer it covers this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that Axios doesn't work in the middleware as it depends on Node.js specific code and the middleware uses the Edge Runtime.

You have two options:

**1. Validate the JWT in the middleware**

You can directly validate the JWT in the NextJS middleware without sending a request to the backend:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { jwtVerify } from 'jose';

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const loginPageUrl = new URL("/auth/login", req.nextUrl.origin).toString();

  // Extract the cookie from the request
  const token = req.cookies["YourCookieName"]; // Replace with the name of your jwt cookie

  if (!token) return NextResponse.redirect(loginPageUrl);

  try {
    // Replace 'your-secret-key' with the secret key used to sign the JWT. You probably want to load this from an environment variable.
    await jwtVerify(token, new TextEncoder().encode("your-secret-key"));

    return NextResponse.next();
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle invalid token cases (e.g., expired token)
    return NextResponse.redirect(loginPageUrl);
  }
}
```

**2. Call the API from the middleware**

This is the same approach as you currently have. But to make it work you have to use `fetch` instead of Axios. Additionally you have to forward the cookie header manually from the request as the middleware doesn't have access to the cookies stored in the browser:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const mainAPI = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAIN_API;
  const loginPageUrl = new URL("/auth/login", req.nextUrl.origin).toString();

  const cookieHeader = req.headers.get('cookie') || '';

    // Make a request to the authentication endpoint
    const authResponse = await fetch(`${mainAPI}/auth/whoami`, {
      headers: {
        Cookie: cookieHeader, // Forward the cookie to the backend
      },
    });

    if ((await authResponse.json()).status !== 'success') {
      // Handle unauthorized access if the auth endpoint responds with an error
      return NextResponse.redirect(loginPageUrl);
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Comment: even validating the jwt in the middleware does not work. I use the npm package `jsonwebtoken` (the original one) and next throws an error saying you can't use crypto module in the edge

Comment: the second solution WORKED! I love you 

Comment: Great :) I've just updated solution one. It uses now "jose" which should run in the Edge Runtime. I would prefer solution one if you don't use any caching on your backend as with solution two, for every navigation a request is made to the `whoami` endpoint.

Comment: where the caching should be? in nextjs or in expressjs?